# How to Display Array Into One DataGridView

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, usertype

I have a Method, which returs Some kind of data, One of them is lets Say FirstClass typed Array. FirstClass contains two properties. 
Can I display this field (I mean FirstClass two properties for all array members) into DatagridView **One** Cell??

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the value of the two properties you need into the first GridView column

[How to show two properties in one column of GRid View asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920108/how-to-show-two-properties-in-one-column-of-grid-view-asp-net-c)

Comment: I'm doing Desktop Application and how can i do the same there?

Comment: I don't think it is that easy in win form world.
why don't you concatenate the property at datasource elvel perhaps adding another property to you datasource that contains the concatenation of them ?